# InputMask with Autocomplete

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-inputmask

I want to make input for dateTime with mask and with autocomplete.

I've created small [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/vbekLtm6/3/) where the problem exists.

Looks like autocomplete thinks mask is a text... only if I finish input I can see some value from autocomplete (if it exists in autocomplete list).

Is there any solution?

```
  <input name="field1" id="field1" class="inputmask" data-inputmask="'mask': 'h:s t\\m','placeholder': 'hh:mm xm', 'hourFormat': '12', 'alias': 'datetime'"/>


function generateTime(){
  var times = [];
  Array(24).join(',').split(',').forEach(function (_, index) {
        var hour = index;
        if (hour < 10) {
            hour = '0' + hour;
        }
        times.push(moment(hour + ':00', 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'));
        times.push(moment(hour + ':30', 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'));
  });

  return times;
}


$('.inputmask').inputmask();
$('.inputmask').autocomplete({
      source: generateTime()
});
```

---

UPD :

Maybe some starting point for solution : In case I will add property `'autoUnmask' : true` AutoComplete will work only for "hours" - first symbols till my ":" in mask.

https://jsfiddle.net/vbekLtm6/5/

Comment: The problem that I see here is that the value in the input never matches the source. If input mask coul allow the value to not be `hh:mm xm` when the field has focus, it would work as expected I think. Must investigate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem here is that the *value* of the `input` is being passed from `inputmask` to `autocomplete`.

1. Check the value of the `input` while entering the value:

   ```js
       function generateTime() {
         var times = [];
         Array(24).join(',').split(',').forEach(function(_, index) {
           var hour = index;
           if (hour < 10) {
             hour = '0' + hour;
           }
           times.push(moment(hour + ':00', 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'));
           times.push(moment(hour + ':30', 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'));
         });
         return times;
       }

       $('.inputmask').inputmask();
       $('.inputmask').autocomplete({
         source: generateTime()
       });

       $('#button').click(function() {
         console.log($('input').val())
       });
   ```

   ```html
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.regex.extensions.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>

       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

       <input name="field1" id="field1" class="inputmask" data-inputmask="'mask': 'h:s t\\m','placeholder': 'hh:mm xm', 'hourFormat': '12', 'alias': 'datetime'" />

       <button id="button">Get</button>
   ```
2. Check the value of the `input` when `autoUnmask: true` has been set up:

   ```js
       function generateTime() {
             var times = [];
             Array(24).join(',').split(',').forEach(function(_, index) {
               var hour = index;
               if (hour < 10) {
                 hour = '0' + hour;
               }
               times.push(moment(hour + ':00', 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'));
               times.push(moment(hour + ':30', 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'));
             });
             return times;
           }

           $('.inputmask').inputmask();
           $('.inputmask').autocomplete({
             source: generateTime()
           });

           $('#button').click(function() {
             console.log($('input').val())
           });
   ```

   ```html
       <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
           <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.regex.extensions.min.js"></script>
           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>

           <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

           <input name="field1" id="field1" class="inputmask" data-inputmask="'mask': 'h:s t\\m','placeholder': 'hh:mm xm', 'hourFormat': '12', 'alias': 'datetime','autoUnmask':true" />

           <button id="button">Get</button>
   ```

I guess by now you'll have got the gist!

So here is the link between the *unmasked* value passed on from `inpumask` to `autocomplete`:

1. Added `label` and `value` to the autocomplete data.
2. Creating a listener to match both `label` and `value` (only `label` matched by default) - [`modeled on the example here`](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#example-1).
3. Also set `autoUnmask: true` and `alias: 'h:s t'`:

   ```
   <input name="field1" id="field1" class="inputmask" data-inputmask="'mask': 'h:s t\\m','placeholder': 'hh:mm xm', 'alias': 'h:s t','autoUnmask':true" />
   ```

[`Updated fiddle here`](https://jsfiddle.net/w03L88pe/) and demo snippet below:

```js
function generateTime() {
  var times = [];
  Array(24).join(',').split(',').forEach(function(_, index) {
    var hour = index;
    if (hour < 10) {
      hour = '0' + hour;
    }
    times.push({
      label: moment(hour + ':00', 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'),
      value: moment(hour + ':00', 'HH:mm').format('hhmma')
    });
    times.push({
      label: moment(hour + ':30', 'HH:mm').format('hh:mm a'),
      value: moment(hour + ':30', 'HH:mm').format('hhmma')
    });
  });

  return times;
}
$('.inputmask').inputmask();
$('.inputmask').autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
    response($.grep(generateTime(), function(value) {
      return matcher.test(value.value) || matcher.test(value.label);
    }));
  }
});

$('#button').click(function() {
  console.log($('input').val())
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.regex.extensions.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>

<input name="field1" id="field1" class="inputmask" data-inputmask="'mask': 'h:s t\\m','placeholder': 'hh:mm xm', 'alias': 'h:s t','autoUnmask':true" />

<button id="button">Get</button>
```